# React-Native metro bundler remove imports with babel transformer keeps bundle size constant

Tags: react-native, babeljs, bundler, metro-bundler

Following situation:

1. I have a `ModuleUtils.ts` file. Inside that file I have some static imports.

   import { a } from 'abc';
   import { b } from 'bcd';
   import { c } from 'cde';
2. I have different .env files for different environments created by: react-native-dotenv

   .env.dev
   .env.int
   .env.live

This .env files contain a modules configuration like following:

```
MODULES=[ a, b, c ]
```

.env.dev e.g. can only contain:

```
MODULES=[ a ]
```

3. I use babel transformer to change the `ModuleFiles.ts` to modify/remove unused or unwanted module imports from that file.

e.g. if the .env.dev configuration is:

```
MODULES=[ a ]
```

then the babel transformers hits the file and remove the imports, so it only consists of:

```
import { a } from 'abc';
```

and the other two

```
import { b } from 'bcd';
import { c } from 'cde';
```

are getting replace/removed. I can see this happening, when I do a console output of the transformed `ModuleUtils.ts` file while metro bundler is running.

I then would suppose, that if the build process is finished and e.g. an APK file is created for an Android build, that the generated index.android.bundle file is smaller than index.android.bundle file where all 3 imports and therefore modules are integrated, but the size of both files is identical, but the APK size is a little bit different. That means the APK file with all three imports/modules is some KB larger than the one with only one module. That shows me, that the process somehow works, but I thought, that the index.android.bundle should also have a different size, but that is not the case, so I am asking why not? I thought, that static imports get bundled by metro bundler into the index.android.bundle file and therefore if I remove some imports they should not be integrated in the index.android.bundle.

Why do I still get the identical index.android.bundle size for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The Metro Bundler consist of 3 processes.

1. Resolution
2. Transformation
3. Serialization

I tried to transform a .ts file (ModuleUtils.ts) with help of the transformation process. The transformation process can change files before they get bundled. Here I tried to remove static imports of my ModuleUtils.ts in hope that the removed imports will not be bundled in the bundle file.
That does not work, because the resolution process is running in parallel of the Transformation process and already decides which modules to integrate in the bundle.

*Metro needs to build a directed graph of all the modules that are required from the entry point to start the building process. To find which file is required from another file Metro uses a resolver.*

Therefore, the transformation process can change the content of a file, but removing imports won't effect the bundle size at all.

To implement a dynamic module imports I would have to do the following for a typescript react project.

1. First remove the imports from the file.
2. Start the build e.g. yarn build:ts, so the typescript files get compiled to javascript files
3. Start the build process e.g. yarn start

I still need to find out how to do the 1) step, but that should be solvable. For example, I could create multiple ModuleUtils.ts files for every .env file I have and blacklist all of them in metro except the one with the correct imports for the specific .env file.

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

// exclusionList is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default exclusions to return a single regex.

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: exclusionList([/dist\/.*/])
  }
};
```